# Arel: Need help converting SQL statement into Arel code for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, relational-database, predicate, arel

Trying to get the following SQL to work in a Rails query.

The Query:

```
select addr.*
  from addresses addr
  join users u
    on addr.addressable_type = 'User'
   and addr.addressable_id = u.id
  join customers c 
    on c.id = u.actable_id
   and u.actable_type = 'Customer' 
 where c.account_id = 1
   and c.site_contact = 't'
```

This is my Rails code:

```
# Inside my account.rb model
def site_addresses
    a = Address.arel_table #Arel::Table.new(:addresses)
    u = User.arel_table #Arel::Table.new(:users)
    c = Customer.arel_table #Arel::Table.new(:customers)

    # trying to debug/test by rendering the sql. Eventually, I want
    # to return a relation array of addresses.
    sql = Address.
      joins(u).
        on(a[:addressable_type].eq("User").and(a[:addressable_id].eq(u[:id]))).
      joins(c).
        on(c[:id].eq(u[:actable_id]).and(u[:actable_type].eq("Customer"))).
     where(c[:account_id].eq(self.id).and(c[:site_contact].eq(true))).to_sql

    raise sql.to_yaml #trying to debug, I'll remove this later
  end
end
```

I'm getting errors like "unknown class: Arel::Table". Im not using Arel correctly because the SQL code is valid (I can run it on the database just fine)

Comment: Dont you need to create an object that represents the table somewhere first?  Like:   address = Arel::Table.new(:address)  in your site_addresses method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
a.join(u).on(a[:addressable_type].eq("User")... # Using the arel_table and "join" instead
```

I based my answer from the [docs](https://github.com/rails/arel):

```
users.join(photos).on(users[:id].eq(photos[:user_id]))
```

Comment: First off, the code sample you have is missing a parenthesis. Please edit your answer to fix that. Second, this is close to what I need but now I have an `Arel::SelectManager` object but I need to turn that into an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so it can send back an array of addresses. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just pointing out the but on the code. For using `ActiveRecord::Relation` you may want to rewrite your code as it has been pointed out in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840944/arel-active-relation-from-arelselectmanager-with-join

Comment: Thanks! This helped!